# How to save the related list data changes from visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, related-list, developer

I'm trying to save the data from visualforce page to salesforce.But after click the save button no action performed.

Please check it once this line

```
<apex:commandButton id="saveBtn1" value="Save" action="{!save}" />
```

### This is my vf page

```
<apex:page standardController="Webinar__c" tabstyle="Adobe_Webinars__tab" sidebar="false" extensions="ConvertWebinarAttendees,WebinarDetailsReport,RedirectPage">
                       <apex:form >  
                     <apex:pageBlock title="Adobe Connect Integration with Salesforce">
                      <div align="right" draggable="false" >       
                            <apex:commandButton value="Logout" action="{!logout}"/>
                        </div><br/>
                         <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!Webinar__c.Name} Details">
                            <apex:outputField value="{!Webinar__c.Name}"/>               
                         </apex:pageBlockSection><br/>
                          <center>
                             <apex:commandButton id="saveBtn" value="Save" action="{!save}" />
                             <apex:commandButton id="cancelBtn" value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" /> 
                             <apex:commandButton id="detleteBtn" value="Delete" action="{!delete}" />               
                          </center><br/>         
                    </apex:pageBlock>    

                     <apex:pageBlock title="{!Webinar__c.Name}  Webinar Attendees ">

                          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wee}" var="w" >                              
                          <apex:column value="{!w.Create_Lead__c}"></apex:column>                           
                            <apex:column headerValue="Webinar Attendee Id">            
                                 <apex:commandLink rerender="RegistrationDetails" value="{!w.principal_id__c}" action="{!ContactLists}">
                                      <apex:param name="id" value="{!w.id}"/>
                                </apex:commandLink>
                           </apex:column>             
                                 <apex:column value="{!w.name}"/>
                                 <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" />
                                 <apex:column value="{!w.Login__c}"></apex:column>              
                         </apex:pageBlockTable>  <br/>
                         <center>

                         // this save() method doesn't working. by clicking save no action performed.


                             <apex:commandButton id="saveBtn1" value="Save" action="{!save}" />
                             <apex:commandButton id="cancelBtn1" value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
                             <apex:commandButton id="leadcreate" value="Create Lead" action="{!getAttendees}"/>
                          </center><br/>   

                        </apex:pageBlock>

                 </apex:form>         
                </apex:page>
```

### And this is my controller

```
public class ConvertWebinarAttendees {

                public ConvertWebinarAttendees(ApexPages.StandardController controller){}

                   Public LightiningEd__Webinar__c Cont{get;set;}
                   public String webinarId {get;set;}

                    List<Lead> LeadList = new List<Lead>();       
                    List<LightiningEd__Webinar__c> waa;

                public void getAttendees(){

                    webinarId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('Id');        
                    waa =[select Id,Name,(SELECT id,Name,LightiningEd__Create_Lead__c,LightiningEd__Company_Name__c,LightiningEd__Attandance_Status__c FROM LightiningEd__Webinar_Attendees_Statuss__r where LightiningEd__Create_Lead__c = TRUE) 
                                                        from LightiningEd__Webinar__c where Id=:webinarId];                         

                    for(LightiningEd__Webinar__c wa: waa){             
                        for(LightiningEd__Webinar_Attendees_Status__c s : wa.LightiningEd__Webinar_Attendees_Statuss__r){                                                 

                                    Lead le = new Lead ();
                                    le.LastName = s.Name;
                                    System.debug('LastName:::'+le.LastName);
                                    le.Status = s.LightiningEd__Attandance_Status__c;
                                    System.debug('Status:::'+le.Status);
                                    le.Company = s.LightiningEd__Company_Name__c;
                                    System.debug('Company:::'+le.Company);
                                    LeadList.add(le);                        
                   }
                 }   
                 /*          
                  if(!LeadList.isEmpty()){         
                       upsert LeadList;
                       update waa;
               }
               */     
             }
             public PageReference save(){

                 upsert LeadList;
                 PageReference Page = new PageReference('/apex/Webinar_Details_Page');
                 Page.setRedirect(true);
                 return Page;   

              }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard Save action with a standard controller extension will only commit changes to the main record to the database. It does not touch related records. To save those, you'll need a custom method that will commit changes to those related records. I see you tried to override the Save method, but that method just updates LeadList, and does nothing to wee.

In your code, you've copied records to LeadList, but you are not making any changes to them. It's pretty confusing code. Is it even compiling? There's wee and waa, and I don't see where you define wee.

Start over, query the records you want to show in your constructor, display them in the table, and write a custom method (not called save) to update the table records.